# Continuous modification of functions with a given property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property:

For all reals $x$, $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to x} f(y)$ exists.

(In particular, note that its possible that $f(x)$ and this limit may differ).

Now define the set 
\begin{equation}
A :=  \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \neq \lim_{y \to x} f(y)\right\}.
\end{equation}
Is there a general characterization of what such a set can be? For instance, is $A$ necessarily countable? A Lebesgue null set? etc.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You should think about continuous, everywhere nondifferentiable functions.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discontinuity set $A$ is at most countable:  Let $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ and let $$A_n=\{x: |f(x)-g(x)|>1/n\}.$$  For each $x\in A_n$, there exists $\delta_x>0$ such that whenever $|y-x|<\delta_x$, necessarily $|f(y)-g(x)|<\frac1{2n}$. 
But then it follows $|g(y)-g(x)|\le \frac1{2n}$, whence $|f(y)-g(y)|\le\frac1n$ and $y\notin A_n$. Thus $A_n$ is discrete, hence countable. Since $A$ is the countable union of the $A_n$, $A$ is countable.